# How to Un-Hide a hidden row in Excel using Apache Poi in Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

if ((currentRow = sheet.getRow(currentDataRow)) == null) {
            currentRow = sheet.createRow(currentDataRow);   // Creates a new row.
        }

// How to un-hide currentRow ?
```

`currentRow` is hidden, so to un-hide this row using this `currentRow` object?

**Please help.. !!**

Comment: What do you mean by `currentRow` is hidden? Also, is `currentRow` an `HSSF` or `XSSF` object?

Comment: In the sheet I am using all rows are made hidden !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's [getRowStyle().setHidden()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html#setHidden%28boolean%29):

```
currentRow.getRowStyle().setHidden(false);
```

More info on [getRowStyle](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#getRowStyle%28%29).

Comment: Please suggest the solution for `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row`, I am not able to find the same function for the ss type row.

Comment: Looks like it's the [*exact* same methods](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setHidden%28boolean%29) for usermodel.

Comment: That is the cell style and not the row style.
currentRow.setHidden() doesn't exists.

Comment: Please look at my answer: it's `row.**getRowStyle()**.setHidden()`.  POI uses the Cell styling class on the rows as well.

Comment: See [the documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getRowStyle%28%29) which shows the return type is CellStyle.

Comment: I got your point... but its strange.. 
that `currentRow.getRowStyle().setHidden(false);` is giving error : `Can-not find symbol getRowStyle()`
According to the API it should be there.. or am I doing some mistake ?

Comment: Check your version?  Maybe you need to upgrade the POI library?

Comment: My POI version is 3.7 !!
So does it supports.. this function call ?

Answer (score 1):

I had poi-3.7 and these methods didn't show up either.

Downloaded the latest one poi-3.8-beta4 and row.setRowStye() and row.getRowStye() are present

Answer (score 0):

[Row.getRowStyle()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getRowStyle()): Returns the whole-row cell styles. Most rows won't have one of these, so will return null.

But you can check if this row is hidden by [row.getZeroHeight()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getZeroHeight()) and show row using row.setZeroHeight(false);