# Why can't an Excel row be 'properly' hidden using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

why is not possible to 'properly' hide an Excel row using Apache POI (3.16)? It is just possible to call (XSSFRow) row.setZeroHeight(), which is also what the [Busy developer's guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Hiding) recommends. However, this is not the same as hiding the row the way Excel does it. You can 'Hide' and 'Unhide' rows with the respective context menu options.

I thought setting the row style should work, but it doesn't. In the resulting Excel file, the row can still be seen.

```
package de.mwe;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class MWE {

@Test
public void testHidingRows() {
    final XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    String sname = "HideRowsTestSheet", cname = "TestName", cvalue = "TestVal";
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet( sname );
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow( 0 );
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell( (short) 0 );
    cell.setCellValue( cvalue );

    XSSFCellStyle hiddenRowStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    hiddenRowStyle.setHidden( true );

    row.setRowStyle( hiddenRowStyle );
    Assert.assertTrue( row.getRowStyle().getHidden() );

    try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream( new File( "target/PoiTestDrive.xlsx" ) )) {
        wb.write( fileOut );
    } catch ( IOException ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // does not work, resulting Excel file shows first row.

}
```

}

Comment: because setHidden is for cells not rows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Un-Hide a hidden row in Excel using Apache Poi in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923153/how-to-un-hide-a-hidden-row-in-excel-using-apache-poi-in-java)

Comment: The [Hiding and Un-Hiding Rows](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Hiding) is correct, except it must be `row.setZeroHeight(true);` for hiding a row. [Row.setZeroHeigh](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#setZeroHeight(boolean)) does exactly what Excel does while hiding a row. For `XSSF` it simply sets hidden property, see https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_16_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.java?view=markup#l423

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Busy developer's guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Hiding) is correct for hiding/unhiding rows. But there is a little error since it must be `row.setZeroHeight(true);` for hiding a row.

The [Row.setZeroHeight(boolean)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#setZeroHeight(boolean)) does exactly what `Excel` does while hiding a row. It works for `HSSF` as well as for `XSSF`. For XSSF it simply sets hidden property to the rows XML, see [XSSFRow.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_16_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.java?view=markup#l423).

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;

public class CreateExcelHiddenRow {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

  for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
   Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("Row " + (r+1));
  }

  Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
  row.setZeroHeight(true);

  //FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelHiddenRow.xls");   
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelHiddenRow.xlsx");   
  wb.write(out);
  out.close();
  wb.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I checked again. Do you know why using the cellStyle does not work?

Comment: `CellStyle` cannot work because the hiding a row is not a cell style but a property of the row. For `XSSF` it is `<row r="2" hidden="true">` in the row's XML.

Comment: Okay, it is somewhat misleading to use the CellStyle class for styling rows if not all properties of the CellStyle apply to rows as well.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new row style. Instead, fetch the rows' existing Style and add your rule:

```
currentRow.getRowStyle().setHidden(true);
```

You kinda can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923153/how-to-un-hide-a-hidden-row-in-excel-using-apache-poi-in-java?rq=1)

Edit: You even create a new **Cell**Style as @RC mentioned.

Comment: Nope, does not work. Removing the creation of the cellStyle and just calling row.getRowStyle().setHidden(true) returns an NPE, because the row initially has no style.